# Data extraction for specific string

Tags: json, bash, bioinformatics, data-extraction, text-manipulation

I have a long list of JSON data, with repeats of contents similar to followings.

Due to the original JSON file is too long, I will just shared the hyperlinks here. This is a result generated from a database called RegulomeDB.

[Direct link to the JSON file](https://regulomedb.org/regulome-search/?regions=chr16:28539847-28539848&genome=GRCh37&format=json)

I would like to extract specific data (eQTLs) from `"method": "eQTLs"` and `"value": "xxxx"`, and put them into 2 columns (tab delimited) exactly like below.
Note: `"value":"xxxx"` is extracted right after `"method": "eQTLs"`is detected.

```
eQTLs   firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult, ...
```

In this example, the desired output is:

```
eQTLs   EIF3S8, EIF3CL
```

I've tried using a python script but was unsuccessful.

```
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
    f_json = json.load(f)
    print 'f_json[0]['"method": "eQTLs"'] + "\t" + f_json[0]["value"]
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Do you have a preferred language for doing this?

Comment: Hi @NickODell, no I don't. But bash would be good.

Comment: Double request with https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19978/eqtl-data-extraction-from-database-json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cat file.json | grep -iE '"method":\s*"eQTLs"[^}]*' -o | cut -d ',' -f 1,5 | sed -r 's/"|:|method|value//gi' | sed 's/\s*eqtls,\s*//gi' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/g' | sed 's/,/, /g' | xargs echo -e 'eQTLs\x09'
```

Comment: Hi @SaSkY, thank you for trying. However, I am getting errors as followings.
grep: invalid option -- P
usage: grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlMmnOopqRSsUVvwXxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @austin7923 I updated the answer please try the command again

Comment: Thanks! It works! But it would be good if the final output could be glued together with a "comma", exactly like the one shown in the post.

Comment: @austin7923 I updated the answer again, can you try it and tell me if it works as you expected ?

Comment: Hi @SaSkY, Some edits need to be done on your command. It works flawlessly now. Thank you!

cat file.json | grep -iE '"method":\s*"eQTLs"[^}]*' -o | cut -d ',' -f 1,5 | sed -r 's/"|:|method|value//gi' | sed 's/\s*eqtls,\s*//gi' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/g' | sed 's/,/, /g' | xargs echo 'eQTLs

Comment: @austin7923 I think you mean the last part `echo -e 'eQTLs\x09'` which did what you asked for print `eQTLs` followed by a literal tab which has the hex value of `09`, but I think what are you talking about are spaces not a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll find the JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) useful. It can open urls and can manipulate strings any way you want:

```
$ xidel -s "https://regulomedb.org/regulome-search/?regions=chr16:28539847-28539848&genome=GRCh37&format=json" \
  -e '"eQTLs&#9;"||join($json("@graph")()[method="eQTLs"]/value,", ")'
eQTLs   EIF3S8, EIF3CL
```

Or with the XPath/XQuery 3.1 syntax:

```
-e '"eQTLs&#9;"||join($json?"@graph"?*[method="eQTLs"]?value,", ")'
```